# How to get maven gwt 2.0 build working

Tags: maven-2, gwt, build-automation

EDIT: Added some of the output of the mvn -X -e commands at the end

My company is developing a GWT application. We've been using maven 2 and GWT 1.7 successfully for quite a while. We recently decided to upgrade to GWT 2.0. We've already updated the eclipse project and we are able to successfully run the application in dev-mode.

We are struggling to get the application built using maven though. I'm hoping somebody can tell me what I'm doing wrong here since I'm running out of time on this.

The exacty bit of the output that worries me is the 'GWT compilation skipped' message:

```
[INFO] Copying 119 resources
[INFO] [compiler:compile {execution: default-compile}]
[INFO] Compiling 704 source files to K:\iCura\assessor\target\classes
[INFO] [gwt:compile {execution: default}]
[INFO] using GWT jars for specified version 2.0.0
[INFO] establishing classpath list (scope = compile)
[INFO] com.curasoftware.assessor.Assessor is up to date. GWT compilation skipped
[INFO] [jspc:compile {execution: jspc}]
[INFO] Built File: \index.jsp
```

I'm pasting the gwt-maven-plugin section below. If you need anything else please ask.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <configuration> 
                <localWorkers>1</localWorkers>
                <warSourceDirectory>${basedir}/war</warSourceDirectory>
                <logLevel>ALL</logLevel>
                <module>${cura.assessor.module}</module>
                <!-- use style OBF for prod -->
                <style>OBFUSCATED</style>                   
                <extraJvmArgs>-Xmx2048m -Xss1024k</extraJvmArgs>
                <gwtVersion>${version.gwt}</gwtVersion>
                <disableCastChecking>true</disableCastChecking>
                <soyc>false</soyc>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>                         
                        <!-- plugin goals -->
                        <goal>clean</goal>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I executed mvn clean install -X -e and this is some of the output that I get:

```
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:1.2:compile' -->
[DEBUG]   (f) disableCastChecking = true
[DEBUG]   (f) disableClassMetadata = false
[DEBUG]   (f) draftCompile = false
[DEBUG]   (f) enableAssertions = false
[DEBUG]   (f) extra = K:\iCura\assessor\target\extra
[DEBUG]   (f) extraJvmArgs = -Xmx2048m -Xss1024k
[DEBUG]   (f) force = false
[DEBUG]   (f) gen = K:\iCura\assessor\target\.generated
[DEBUG]   (f) generateDirectory = K:\iCura\assessor\target\generated-sources\gwt
[DEBUG]   (f) gwtVersion = 2.0.0
[DEBUG]   (f) inplace = false
[DEBUG]   (f) localRepository = Repository[local|file://K:/iCura/lib]
[DEBUG]   (f) localWorkers = 1
[DEBUG]   (f) logLevel = ALL
[DEBUG]   (f) module = com.curasoftware.assessor.Assessor
[DEBUG]   (f) project = MavenProject: com.curasoftware.assessor:assessor:3.5.0.0 @ K:\iCura\assessor\pom.xml
[DEBUG]   (f) remoteRepositories = [Repository[gwt-maven|http://gwt-maven.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/mavenrepo/], Repository[main-maven|http://www.ibiblio.org/maven2/], Repository[central|http://repo1.maven.org/maven2]]
[DEBUG]   (f) skip = false
[DEBUG]   (f) sourceDirectory = K:\iCura\assessor\src
[DEBUG]   (f) soyc = false
[DEBUG]   (f) style = OBFUSCATED
[DEBUG]   (f) treeLogger = false
[DEBUG]   (f) validateOnly = false
[DEBUG]   (f) warSourceDirectory = K:\iCura\assessor\war
[DEBUG]   (f) webappDirectory = K:\iCura\assessor\target\assessor
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
```

and then this:

```
[DEBUG] SOYC has been disabled by user
[DEBUG] GWT module com.curasoftware.assessor.Assessor found in K:\iCura\assessor\src
[INFO] com.curasoftware.assessor.Assessor is up to date. GWT compilation skipped
[DEBUG] com.curasoftware.assessor:assessor:war:3.5.0.0 (selected for null)
[DEBUG]   com.curasoftware.dto:dto-gen:jar:3.5.0.0:compile (selected for compile)
...
```

It's finding the correct sourceDirectory. That folders has a 'com' folder within which ultimately is the source of the application organized in folders as per the package structure.

Comment: The obvious question: have you performed a `mvn clean` command? If yes, I'd try to compile with the `-e` flag - it might give more details about what's happening behind the scenes.

Comment: So `K:\iCura\assessor\target\generated-sources\gwt` is empty after  `gwt:compile`?

Comment: @pascal K:\iCura\assessor\target\generated-sources\ doesn't exist

Answer (score 1):

As stated by Geoffrey Wiseman, you may be running into jira.codehaus.org/browse/MGWT-151, which happens when the module you're building doesn't have an entry point (presumably because you're inheriting from a module that does). While the issue says that it's fixed in 2.1.0, you can actually use the 1.3-SNAPSHOT version of the gwt-maven-plugin and it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the declaration, as per [the compile example in the plugin documentation](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/examples/compile.html)

> You can also ignore the ''module'' parameter, so that the plugin will scan your project for gwt.xml module files.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Does setting inplace = true help ? http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/compile-mojo.html#inplace

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I've got the same problem under GWT 1.7.1 with gwt-maven-plugin 1.2 and <inplace>true</inplace> hasn't helped.